# jQuery: Changing one class with multiple buttons

Tags: jquery

I am simply trying to change a background color on a div using multiple buttons, the code I have come up with so far works but just keeps on adding more classes to the .eaStaff container div rather than toggling them, I tryed originally using .attr but I need to keep the class .eaStaff, using .attr removed/replaced that class.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kellyhawker/p34r7m87/4/)

```
//BG COLOUR
$('.bg a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('dd', $(this).data('class'))
    $('.eaStaff').toggleClass($(this).data('class'));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toggle class either removes or adds a specific class to an element, it doesn't clear other classes. Instead you can remove the other classes before adding that class.

```
$('.eaStaff').removeClass('transBG darkBg lightBg');
$('.eaStaff').addClass($(this).data('class'));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p34r7m87/5/

Comment: No problem, if that answers your question completely, please mark this as the answer, thanks.